# Menuitem align to left in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have three MenuItems,

```
<MenuItem x:Name="Menu1" Header="Menu1" />
<MenuItem x:Name="LoginMenu" Header="Login" />
<MenuItem x:Name="LogoutMenu" Header="Logout" />
```

When application load, I changed the MenuItems (except 3rd) visibility to `Hidden` and when I click on Login menu item I need to change the visibility to `Visible`. How can I left align the menu items when changing the visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `Visibility` to `Hidden` set it to `Collapsed`. So the space of the collapsed-menuitem will be free. If you set the `Visibility` to `Hidden` the space the hidden items need will be reserved.